# How to convert this CocoaScript “braces notation” to JavaScript “dot notation” (sketch)?

Tags: javascript, syntax, sketch-3, sketchapp, cocoascript

How to convert these CocoaScript “braces notation” to JavaScript “dot notation” syntax?

```
[fileManager createDirectoryAtPath: tmpFolder withIntermediateDirectories: true attributes: nil error: nil];
```

and

```
[doc saveArtboardOrSlice: artboard toFile: fileName]
```

I've struggling with the CocoaScript “braces notation” format and want to use JavaScript instead combining them. I'm not sure if this even possible in all cases, like above. I get almost everything to work, but when I've syntax like above, I do not get it to right.

I tried something like:

```
var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager();
fileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(tmpFolder).withIntermediateDirectories(true).attributes(nil).error(nil);
```

So I do not understand how to convert these "inner variables/properties", those which are e.g. "withIntermediateDirectories: true" to JavaScript dot notation syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent of:

```
[foo bar:1 baz:2];
```

is:

```
foo.bar_baz_(1, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks Roman! This leads me to right direction and got it to work properly. I didn't know about using "_" underscore marks in that way. So right syntax for my problem was: `fileManager.createDirectoryAtPath_withIntermediateDirectories_attributes_error(tmpFolder, true, null, null);`